# How to create the directory by using shell script?

Tags: shell

I have started learning about shell scripting a day ago.I got baffling about creating a directory. The scenario is, If we run the script.script should ask for the path to create the directory and if we specify the path, directory should be created in the specified path.Please suggest your thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: first search google, stackoverflow. if you are stuck *then* ask here.

Comment: While this is a really broad question, currently (2022) it is first google result when searching "shell create folder", so it helped and I upvoted :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the path is stored in the variable `path`, then do

```
mkdir "$path"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your script.sh should have:
mkdir -p $1

Run it as: ./script.sh a/b/c
This will create the folder structure a/b/c in current working dir.
The -p option in mkdir above is to create directories structures.